# Difference between the path with and without '/'?

Tags: python, linux, file, ubuntu

I'm new to Python, and currently using the `os` module. I came across a doubt.

Can anyone explain me, what is the difference between the following lines?

```
os.mkdir('dir_name')
os.mkdir('/dir_name')
```

The former creates the folder in the current directory but what about the later? There's no folder created in the current directory, where is it created then?

Comment: The first is a _relative_, the second an _absolute_ path. A relative path is interpreted relative to the current working directory your process is in, an absolute path is interpreted from the systems file system root node (`/`).

Comment: The 2nd is an *absolute* path and will be created in the *FS* root ("*/*", or directly on the drive returned as part of by `os.getcwd()`).

Comment: The second creates the folder in the root directory ('/'). This usually requires root privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
os.mkdir('dir_name')  # relative
```

The first path is ***relative***. The first code line will make a directory "dir_name" in the current working directory. It is relative because the path will change *relative* to the working directory.

```
os.mkdir('/dir_name')  # absolute
```

This second path is ***absolute***. "/" refers the the operating system's root directory. The second code snippet will make a "dir_name" directory in the root directory. The path is *absolute* because unlike the "current working directory", the root directory will never change.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `os.mkdir('../dir_name')` for full picture. It is also a relative, but uses `..` to denote upper level folder, relative to current one.